# Determine $L(x,y,z)$ when you have $L(1,1,0), L(1,2,1),L(0,1,2),L(3,5,2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following question:

L is linear transformation :$R^3->R^3$ such that $L(1,1,0)=(0,0,1), L(1,2,1)=(2,1,2) ,L(0,1,2)=(2,0,0),L(3,5,2)=(4,2,5)$

Determine $L(7,12,100)$

What's the fastest way to do that? I was thinking about finding the matrix representation but couldn't find a way.

I got the matrix with the given vectors as its columns which is wrong. (no dimension compatibility)

Comment: Write $(7,12,100)$ as a linear combination of $(1,1,0)$, $(1,2,1)$ and $(0,1,2)$. Then apply $L$.

Comment: this seemed to me like too long, that is what I thought of first, is this the fastest way?

Comment: This is not too long, it is very quick. Finding the matrix isn't the fastest way, in particular when you say "but I couldn't find a way". Better to proceed systematically so that you understand each step.

Comment: Did you mean $L(3,5,2)=(4,2,5)?\;$  You don't need that really

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes I corrected this

Comment: @DietrichBurde I would get an augmented matrix with 3 rows and 5 columns, hence infinitely many solutions, that is why I hesitated to go for it, what would you suggest

Comment: If $L$ is linear then $L(3,5,2)=L((1,1,0)+2(1,2,1))$ $=L(1,1,0)+2L(1,2,1)$ $=(0,0,1)+2(2,1,2)=(4,\color{red}2,5)$

Comment: Not true with infinitely many solution. There is a unique solution to the system, namely $x=97,z=95,y=-90$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner this was an exam question and I got it wrong, I just copied here to learn how to solve it, you are right

Comment: @DietrichBurde what about the w? for reference:  https://imgur.com/a/X1BUURC

Comment: @ayrebelcoding Sorry, I don't view pictures. The system is  $x+y-7=0,x+2y+z=12$ and $y+2z=100$, right?

Comment: I got $x+y+3w=100, x+2y+z+5w=12, y+2z+2w=100$, I used all 4 columns. Can we just remove any column we want?

Comment: The first three vectors are already linearly independent. We don't need any fourth variable $w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine $L(7,12,100),$

first express $(7,12,100)$ as a linear combination of $(1,1,0),(1,2,1),$ and $(0,1,2)$:

$$a(1,1,0)+b(1,2,1)+c(0,1,2)=(7,12,100).$$

$$(a+b,a+2b+c,b+2c)=(7,12,100)$$

From the first component, we see that $a=7-b$, and, from the third, $c=(100-b)/2$.

From the second component, therefore, $7-b+2b+(100-b)/2=12$.

Thus, $45=-b/2$.  From here, can you solve for $a,b, $ and $c$ and then use $$L(7,12,100)=L(a(1,1,0)+b(1,2,1)+c(0,1,2))$$

$$=aL(1,1,0)+bL(1,2,1)+cL(0,1,2)=a(0,0,1)+b(2,1,2)+c(2,0,0)?$$

Comment: so we we get $(10, -90, -83)$!

Comment: That's what I got ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but $(a+b,a+2b+c,b+2c)=(7,12,100)$ is not true for $(a,b,c)=(10,-90,-83)$. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I mean $L(7,12,100)=(10,-90,-83)$